# select if value included in the string

Tags: php, sql

```
$string = 'US|UK|AUS|CA';
```

I'm trying to do something like this

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE country (included in $string)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string is sanitized, I would explode the string into an array and use `implode` to create the statement. You shouldn't be storing multiple values in a string. That's what arrays are for.

```
$string = 'US|UK|AUS|CA';
$string = explode('|', $string);

$stmt = "SELECT ... country IN ('" . implode("', '", $string) . "')";
```

Produces

```
SELECT ... country IN ('US', 'UK', 'AUS', 'CA')
```

Answer (score 2):

just explode your string with "|" to get the array and then implode that array with "," to get the string.

```
$string = 'US|UK|AUS|CA';
$string=explode("|",$string);
$new_string=implode("', '",$string);
```

then just run the query  like this

```
select username from table where country IN ('".$new_string."');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
SELECT username FROM table WHERE instr($string,country) > 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT username FROM table WHERE country in('US', 'UK', 'AUS', 'CA')`

Comment: no, can't do it directly like that..sting value can be diffrent

Comment: there is no problem.
u can use $string as an array variable with any values

Comment: how please ?? it's separated with |

Comment: `$string = ['US','UK','AUS','CA'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM table WHERE country in('".$string."') ");`

Answer (score 0):

If they are gonna be different... You can try to use an Array

Something like:

```
$countries= array('a','b','c');
```

then you go for a

```
$q="SELECT username FROM table WHERE country in(".implode("','",$countries).")
```

The implode will convert array keys in a single string separated by the `,`

Answer (score -1):

$string = 'UK' OR 'US' OR 'AUS' OR 'CA'